# getStaticProps revalidate stops after a whilein ISR

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i'm using nextjs 12.1.6.

i used revalidate parameter in getStaticProps for home page to revalidate page every 10 seconds (ISR).

but there is a problem and that's revalidate only works for several times and stops after a while.

it's my code:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  captureMessage("fetching homeData");
  console.log(new Date().toISOString(), " | fetching home data");
  try {
    const [homeData] = await getHomeData();

    if (!homeData.data || homeData.error) {
      console.log(`getHomeData : ${homeData.error}`);
      captureMessage("getHomeData" + JSON.stringify(homeData.error));
      throw `getHomeData : ${JSON.stringify(homeData.error)}`;
    }

    return {
      props: {
        data: homeData.data,
      },
      revalidate: 10,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    captureMessage("error in fetching: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    console.log("error in fetching: ", err);
    throw `Error in fetching : ${err}`;
  }
};
```

i wrote some logging to sentry. and it's works for a while after first build on CI/CD. but after a while i don't receive any issue (message) of getStaticProps.

i didn't find any issue or helpful article.
but i tried it without try,catch and with it. but problem still happens.